# GPO startup script keeps re-installing appls

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2022

Hi I have the following issue. I have a PowerShell script to install software on domain users pcs using a GPO running on Active Directory Server.
It installs the software successfully but when I restart the pc it runs the script again and re-installs the software.
the script is below

```
#Script to install exe via GPO

$folder = 'C:\Program Files\Mind+' //the folder where it should be installed

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $Folder)) {
   
    start-process -FilePath "\\IT-SERVER.G-TESEK.com\APP-DEPLOYEMENT\mind+\Mind+_Win_V1.8.0_RC1.0.exe" -ArgumentList '/S'

    }

else  { }
```

Can someone help?. How do I have it only runs if the software is not already installed?

I have made the following edits using the sugestion from @NarayanaList and it works however when trying to log the result it fails. If I run it locally it works the result however when running it using GPO it does not any ideas?.

```
# Specify the name of the program you want to check
$programName = "Wireshark"

# Specify the path to the installer executable
$newInstallerPath = "\\IT-SERVER.G-TESEK.com\APP-DEPLOYEMENT\wireshark\Wireshark-win64-4.0.10.exe"

# Specify the path to the log file
$logFilePath = "\\IT-SERVER.G-TESEK.com\APP-DEPLOYEMENT\log_installed.txt"

# Function to check if a program is installed based on the registry path
function Is-ProgramInstalled {
    param (
        [string]$registryPath
    )

    # Attempt to find programs with names containing the specified programName
    $installedProgram = Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                       Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*$programName*" }

    # Return true if the program is installed; otherwise, return false
    return [bool]($installedProgram -ne $null)
}

# Registry path for 64-bit programs
$x64RegistryPath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

# Registry path for 32-bit programs on 64-bit systems
$x86RegistryPath = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

# Get the computer host name
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

# Get the current date and time
$currentTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

# Check if the program is installed
$programInstalled = Is-ProgramInstalled -registryPath $x64RegistryPath
if (-not $programInstalled) {
    $programInstalled = Is-ProgramInstalled -registryPath $x86RegistryPath
}

# If the program is not installed, install it
if (-not $programInstalled) {
    Write-Host "$programName is not installed. Installing now..."

    # Install the program
    Write-Host "Installing $programName..."
    Start-Process -FilePath $newInstallerPath -ArgumentList '/S' -Wait

    $logMessage = "$currentTime - $computerName $programName has been installed successfully."
} else {
    $logMessage = "$currentTime - $computerName $programName is already installed."
}

# Log the result to the file
Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logMessage
Write-Host "Log entry added to $logFilePath"
Write-Host $logMessage
```

Comment: Where do you know it installs it again and again?

Comment: I can see it on the users pc it uninstall's it and re-installs it.

Comment: Found the issue, the program was installed in the  C:\Program Files (x86)\Mind+ and the script was testing for C:\Program Files\Mind+.  Now I need a way to check if the executable is installed in either X86 or X64 before trying to install

Comment: Does the setup executable decides for itself what bit version to install? That sounds unlikely. 

Comment: Please try to check whether this application is installed or not using Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'Mind+'"  .Then you can install it again if it is not installed

Comment: @NarayanaLvsl Using the `Win32-Product` class is usually a bad idea. [Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software. Alternatives Inside!](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/) .... and [Win32_Product Is Evil.](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/)